# How to remove the selected data from an array in vue js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I am in the need of splicing a data from the array, for which i have used the following,

Html:

```
           <div id="app">
                <select v-model="facilityAvailable" name="facilities" multiple="multiple" id="facilities" size="4" class="form-control">
                  <option v-for="availability in availableFacilities" v-bind:value="availability">{{availability.label}}--</option>
                </select>
                <a @click="removeFacilities" class="btn btn-default remove_option" rel="facilities2" id="remove"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></a>
                <a @click="addFacilities" class="btn btn-default add_option" rel="facilities2" id="add"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
                <select v-model="facilitySelected" name="facilities" multiple="multiple" id="facilities2" size="4" class="form-control">
                  <option v-for="facility in selectedFacilities" v-bind:value="facility">{{facility.label}}</option>
                </select>

            </div>
```

Script:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   facilityAvailable: [],
      facilitySelected:[],
      availableFacilities: [{
        value: 0,
        label: 'Double (Non a/c)'
      },
      {
        value: 1,
        label: 'Premium Double (a/c)'
      },
      {
        value: 2,
        label: 'Standard Double (a/c)'
      }
    ],
    selectedFacilities: [],
  },
  methods: {
    removeFacilities() {
    this.availableFacilities = this.facilitySelected.concat(this.availableFacilities);
    this.selectedFacilities.splice(this.availableFacilities.value,1);
    },
    addFacilities() {
    this.selectedFacilities = this.facilityAvailable.concat(this.selectedFacilities);
    this.availableFacilities.splice(this.selectedFacilities.value,1);
    }
  }
})
```

Here i am doing like transfer of one element from one select box to the other to another select box, for which i have used `concat` for adding to another and `splice` to remove that element.. Everything was fine upto this. But when i `splice` , it is splicing in the order of `0,1,2` i need to splice based on the  index number of that particular element. In clear, i can select and remove the element in any order for which that particular element needs to be removed and gets transferred into second select box, whereas now if i remove it in the order as it was , its working fine but whereas if i change the order and splice its not working. Also when i select multiple elements and remove, the same thing happening. Kindly help me to solve this issue.

The fiddle link was,  https://jsfiddle.net/pmvp3td6/9/

Comment: What you get in `index` in your methods is just the standard `MouseEvent` object.

Comment: addFacilities() { var that = this; console.log(that); - that should be the selected element, anyway in plain js, but not sure in vue.

Comment: @connexo Updated my fiddle by removing index..

Comment: The solution you refer to is different in nature. It uses a list, not a select element. While creating the list, the author gave it `v-for="(item, index) in items"` and created a button for each iteration. You have a button completely outside of your iteration block, so index won't be available where you expect it.

Comment: @connexo, I got your point and now i have updated it with getting the value of availableFacilities.. But i think the way i am approaching is wrong.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pmvp3td6/13/ Is that what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: @connexo, Yes its making transfer of the selected element but I am able to transfer only one value.. I am in the need to transfer all the value to another select box.

Comment: Hope my fiddle helps you get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure i understood right what you are looking for but try with that in your addFacilities :

```
 addFacilities() {
    let i = 0;
    for(i; i<this.facilityAvailable.length;i++){ 
        this.selectedFacilities.push(this.facilityAvailable[i]);
        this.availableFacilities = this.availableFacilities.filter(facilities => facilities.value != this.facilityAvailable[i].value);
    }
}
```

If that's what you want you can do something similar in the remove part

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Element-UI's Transfer component](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/transfer). This should solve your problem.